# Show image from database with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a problem displaying a blob image from my database using PHP.

I use the following to display the image: `echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style="width:300px;height:300px">';` That code shows a broken image. If i click view image info it gives me this:

```
Location: http://mywebsite.com/12300_110715682290093_100000549846650_157528_4480259_n.jpg
Type: text/html
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: the type says it all. the server is outputting text/html, not image/jpeg or whatever it should be.

Comment: You could show the php code that generate the image. Maybe you don't have set the correct headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714163/proper-header-php-mysql-blob-display-image

Answer (score 0):

The best way to show a image from database is to upload the image to a folder where you have your site and then upload the image name to the database.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp here you can read about file upload.

Tell me if you need the code to do it.